# Isp connected to lan port, want to access Internet via wifi

Tags: internet-connection

I have dlink dir 600 n 150 home wireless router with one wan port and four lan port. My isp line is connected to lan port 1 and my computer is connected is connected to lan port 2, nothing is connected to wan port. I want to access Internet on mobile using wifi but since nothing ia connected to wan port hence cant.
So how can i make lan connection available on wifi.

Comment: Why is your ISP connected to Lan 1? It should be connected to Wan.

Comment: When ISP provider tried to connect line to wan port it cant access Internet. But when connected to lan port then i can access Internet on computer. I dont know why he has connection like this

Comment: Regarding the WAN/LAN port, I think you will need to enable something called "bridge mode" or "passthrough mode" on your modem before you can connect it to the WAN port.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, your computer is able to access the internet, correct?